# Why does maximum photoluminescence intensity increase for longer time delays?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Consider an emission spectrum of GaInAs semiconductor at two different times after a sample has been excited with an ultrashort pulse. For a longer time elapsed, (240 ps, see image), the spectrum becomes thinner (carrier density decreases) and emission shifts to being only at energies close to $E_g$.

My question is why does the relative $\textit{maximum}$ intensity for this curve increase when the time elapsed goes from 24 ps to 250 ps?

[image: Fox, Optical Properties of Solids, Figure 5.8]

Figure 5.8 from $\textit{Optical Properties of Solids}$ (M.Fox).